# Cannot read property in vue.js issue how to fix?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm passing it like a prop like
    props : [ 'user'],

Then does it like this in the data object

```
    form : {        
                id : this.user.id , 
                birthplace : this.user.profile.birthplace,
```

> [Vue warn]: Error in data(): "TypeError: Cannot read property 'birthplace' of null"
>   found in

--->  at resources/assets/js/components/EditCriminal.vue
       
warn @ app.js:80633
app.js:81896 TypeError: Cannot read property 'birthplace' of null

Comment: Can you please provide a full example of the relevant code of the vue file?
I'm not sure what I'm looking at in your snippet

Comment: the template of the file ??

Comment: I used it like   
```<places v-model="form.birthplace" class="bg-grey-lighter w-full mb-2 p-2 leading-normal" id="pin" placeholder="Enter the full location details" @change="val => { form.birthplace = val }">
                    </places>
```

Comment: It seems that initially you are passing null data to the EditCriminal component and at a later point you update that data with a new valid one.

Comment: I meant the vue file of the snippet above. Anyway it looks like `this.user.profile` is null. Without the full code it's hard to tell why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to pass the value of the `prop` to `data` items like this:

```
data(){
     return{
          form{
               id:null,
               birthplace:null
          }
     }
},
props:['user'],
created(){
     if(this.user){
          this.form.id = this.user.id;
          if(this.user.profile)
               this.form.birthplace = this.user.profile.birthplace,
     }
}
```

Comment: You better do this in `created()` instead of `mounted()`.

Comment: Hey brother how tdo u simplify those kinds of entries in the form for example , I have multiple fields there that's the same with this.criminals.profile.country for example is equal to the `form.country`